# How to hide group title within SimpleForm

Tags: sapui5

I want to hide the title starts a new group. I tried it by setting visible to false and tried to add custom CSS classes as well. It did not work. How can I hide the group title within a SimpleForm.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you intend to hide the title, but still need to maintain the groups

Comment: yes I have to maintain the group without title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be possible to hide the sub header while maintaining groups with the control properties. However with some CSS it is achievable

Add a custom CSS class to the SimpleForm control

```
<f:SimpleForm class="formHiddenTitle" ...
```

The CSS would be as below :

```
.formHiddenTitle .sapUiFormContainerTitle .sapUiFormTitle{
    display:none;
}
```

This will hide all Form Title tags in all all groups.

Comment: As of 1.71 this cuts of part of the form on devices where sapUiSizeCozy is active :(

Comment: @Marc I haven't seen UI5 for some years now, you could maybe update the answer....